# react-native-code-push uses deprecated "rnpm" How to remove warning

Tags: react-native, npm, code-push, react-native-code-push

I have implemented a `code push` in my project when I run the project it showing the following `deprecation` warning.

How to solve this warning?

[More About issue](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/1633)

[react-native-code-push/issues/1625](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/1625)

```
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
- react-native-code-push: https://microsoft.github.io/code-push
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react- 
native- 
community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
```

> Packaje.json

```
"dependencies":
 {
   "react": "16.9.0",
   "react-native": "0.61.1",
   "react-native-code-push": "^5.7.0"
 }
```

> node_modules_reactnativecodepush_package.json

[Some thing related to this](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide)

```
"rnpm": {
"android": {
  "packageInstance": "new CodePush(getResources().getString(R.string.reactNativeCodePush_androidDeploymentKey), getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.DEBUG)"
},
"ios": {
  "sharedLibraries": [
    "libz"
  ]
},
"commands": {
  "postlink": "node node_modules/react-native-code-push/scripts/postlink/run",
  "postunlink": "node node_modules/react-native-code-push/scripts/postunlink/run"
}
},

  "typings": "typings/react-native-code-push.d.ts",
  "version": "5.7.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning was removed in new `react-native-code-push@6.0.0` version.  https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/releases/tag/v6.0.0
Use this version in hour app. Make a note that setup steps were chaged.